# Unable deserialize non-model field in modelSerializer in DRF3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, geodjango

This question might seem redundant but I have searched for other answers and they didn't seem to solve the problem. I am using GeoDjango with DRF3. I have a field in my models named location, whose value is given as Point instance which takes longitude and latitude as argument.

Therefore, in serializer I have two non-model fields - latitude and longitude. However, when I print the `validated_data`, lat and lng aren't getting deserialized.

## Update

I have removed `serialzerMethodField` for `latitude` and `longitude` and have replaced them with `location` field as I have in my models.

models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    site_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="site")

    location = models.PointField(geography=True, null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.FloatField(null=True)
    objects = SiteManager()
```

managers.py

```
class SiteManager(BaseManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create(self, owner, **kwargs):
        print('kwargs is ',kwargs)
        site = self.model(
            owner = owner,
            area = kwargs['area'],
            location=Point(float(kwargs['location']['latitude']), float(kwargs['location']['longitude'])),
        )

        site.save(using=self._db)

        print('site is ',site)

        return site
```

serializers.py

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('location', 'area')


# Serializer to get user details
class UserSiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = SiteSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('fullName', 'email', 'site')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        site_data = validated_data.pop('site')
        user = InterestedUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Site.objects.create(owner=user, **site_data)
        return user
```

Request data is:
`{'fullName': 'rtyhgf', 'email': '8sdfggfs@er.com', 'site': {'location': {'longitude': 72.81919139881033, 'latitude': 18.925400020910235}, 'area': 636.865234375}`

when I print `site_data` in `create` method of `UserSiteSerializer`, I get `OrderedDict([('area', 636.865234375)])`

Comment: ```return validated_data['latitude']``` instead of ```print(validated_data['latitude'])```?

Comment: @waynetech I had tried that but it didn't work. At present, I am trying by removing ```serializerMethod``` fields and replacing it with location in ```fields```. In ```repr``` it gives me that field as ```modelField```. However, now I am getting ```AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'location'```

Answer (score 0):

`SerializerMethodField` is used for readonly fields. You should write your serializer like this.

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latitude = serializers.FloatField(source='get_latitude')
    longitude = serializers.FloatField(source='get_longitude')

    def get_latitude(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data['latitude'])

    def get_longitude(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data['longitude'])

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('latitude', 'longitude', 'area')
```